# VBA: I can add formulas to a range of cells, but not to 1 cell

Tags: vba, excel

I think I've tried most everything and I always get the dreaded Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Dim wsMaster As Workbook
Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook
(Other stuff)
With wsMaster.Worksheets(1)
    .Activate
    .Range(Cells(startRow, 20), Cells(endRow, 25)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC15/R" & startRow & "C16"
    .Range(Cells(startRow, 26), Cells(startRow, 31)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-6]:R" & endRow & "C[-6])"
    .Range("R" & startRow & "C16").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R" & startRow & "C[-1]:R" & endRow & "C[-1]"
End With
```

The interesting part is that the code only throws an error on the third formula assignment line. The other lines function as intended and insert the proper formulas in the specified range. I've tried a myriad of different ways to reference the cell, but I get the error every time.

I checked with the locals screen and startRow is properly set at 2 and endRow is properly set at 8.

I'd appreciate any help with this mysterious issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right off the bat I notice you are missing a : (Colon)

```
.Range("R" & startRow & "C16") should be

.Range("R" & startRow & ":C16")
```

The other issues I noticed are with the third formula.  You are missing your brackets and a parenthesis:

```
"=SUM(R" & startRow & "C[-1]:R" & endRow & "C[-1]" should be:

"=SUM(R[" & startRow & "]C[-1]:R[" & endRow & "]C[-1])"
```

Here is the entire third line, with your same format, with the above referenced corrections.

```
.Range("R" & startRow & ":C16").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & startRow & "]C[-1]:R[" & endRow & "]C[-1])"
```

Comment: Ended up using a .Cells(startRow, 16) reference as opposed to .Range, but I think it was the closing parenthesis that was causing the issue! Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Either or work! Hang on to both for various reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

To reference a single cell, you can use the `Cells(row, column)` property.

In your code, change

```
.Range("R" & startRow & "C16").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R" & startRow & "C[-1]:R" & endRow & "C[-1]"
```

To

```
.Cells(startRow, 16).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R" & startRow & "C[-1]:R" & endRow & "C[-1]"
```